# How can I redeploy my react website on firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, frontend, hosting

Actually, I have deployed a website on firebase. I found a bug and fixed that, but the problem is how can I now redeploy it on firebase.

I know one method where I will first disable the hosting by running command `firebase hosting:disable` and then go to firebase and delete it. After that, deploy it again.

I wanna know is that the ideal method or is there any alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run `firebase deploy` (or `firebase deploy --only hosting`, if you have multiple resources defined in your local firebase project) to update the deployed site.